# Issue exporting `express()` and `ws()` objects to other files in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

Let's say the entry point of my app is `app.js`
I want to create a socket connect when the app runs and then export it to other files throughout the application.

Here is a bit of example code

```
const express = require('express');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const app = express();
app.use(allTheMiddleWares);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('started app');
}

const socket = new WebSocket.Server({server: app});

module.exports = socket;
```

Then when I try to access the export from `app.js` I always end up with an empty object.

I have also tried exporting functions:

```
module.exports = { 
    test: () => console.log("why don't I work")
}
```

However this also returns an empty object.

Thanks in advance for the help.

As a temporary work around to access the socket globally I have set `process.WebSocket = new WebSocket.Server({server: app});`. I would like to know if there are any glaring issues with this.

Comment: PS. The code above isn't real. Just an illustration.

Comment: Can you try `export default socket;` instead of `module.exports = socket;`?

Comment: When you get an empty object on import, it's often because of circular module dependencies where A imports B and B imports A.  You don't know enough of your code for us to be able to see if that is the issue or not.

Comment: Also, `new WebSocket.Server({server: app});` looks wrong because `app` is not a server (it's an Express requeset handler function).  `app.listen()` returns the server object that is created.

Comment: We can't help further without seeing BOTH files, the one where you are exporting and the one where you are importing.  There's nothing wrong with `module.exports = socket;` so there must be something else going on here.  And, using a `global` is a BAD idea and a bad trend to start.  Fix the problem the right way.

Comment: @jfriend00 the issue was I needed to write `server = app.listen()` then using `WebSocket.Server({server})` worked. Thank you very much. I wasn't aware that express returned anything when calling listen. Anyway you solved all my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it was your solution.

You are not passing a server to the WebSocket constructor.  `app` is a request handler.  It is not a server.  `app.listen()` returns a newly created server object.

Change your code from this:

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('started app');
}

const socket = new WebSocket.Server({server: app});
```

to this:

```
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('started app');
}

const socket = new WebSocket.Server({server: server});
```

---

See code for `app.listen()` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L616).

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

See doc for `app.listen()` [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen).

> The app.listen() method returns an http.Server object and (for HTTP) is a convenience method for the following: